# How can I unit test this Play Scala controller using Specs2?

Tags: mongodb, scala, unit-testing, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have the following controller code which connects to a MongoDB instance, retrieves some data then maps the data to a JSON list of friends, how can I unit test it using Specs2?

```
object Friends extends Controller with MongoController {

  def collection: JSONCollection = db.collection[JSONCollection]("friends")

  def list = Action.async {
    val cursor: Cursor[Friend] = collection.find(Json.obj()).cursor[Friend]

    val futureFriendList: Future[List[Friend]] = cursor.collect[List]()

    futureFriendList.map { friends => Ok(Json.toJson(futureFriendList)) }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you managed so far? You can use `Await.result` to get the value from the asynchronous call in your tests.